# Transformation Matlab assignments to Mathematica expressions

Tags: matlab

From a simulation software, I obtain in a matlab file my algebro-differential equations in the following way :

C_p_e = C_state/C_c;

C_p_f = I_state/I_i;

R_p_e = R_r*C_p_f;

I_p_e = (Se_p_e-R_p_e)-C_p_e;

For theses expressions, I would like to do two operations :
1) Transform it into equations
2) Conduct substitutions so as to change the names of the variables with nicer names.

For this objectives, I would like to automatisation the creation of the four equations eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4. For the moment, to create these equations, I only do copy/ paste from matlab but i have models with far more equations.

How can I create equations labeled eq1, ...eqn from this list of expressions (or more assignments in matlab) from Matlab in Mathematica?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What format is the file? Can you import the equations as strings?

Comment: I have .m file from Matlab. Here i only make copy/ paste from this file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very useful help. It seems that the code is very closed to one that I wanted. However, I have a problem at the end with 'list = StringSplit[comm2, ";\n"]
Scan[(eqn[#] = list[[#]]) &, Range@Length@list]' It seems that these lines are not working. Is it possible for me to send you my code ? Otherwise, may you tell me how I can easily show you the status of my code. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It's not working because I forgot an essential part, which is to do `ToExpression`. See edited answer (fix is at end).

Comment: Thank you your code works perfectly. It remains me only the step of variables substitutions to make the equations nicer. But, my code seems not working.
May you have a look to my lastest code ?
The 3 first commands are identic
and after
list = StringSplit[comm2, ";"]
list = Replace[
  list, {cC[p, e] -> fs[t], cC[p, f] -> v[t], rR[p, e] -> fd[t], 
   iI[p, e] -> fm[t], cC[c] = 1/k, iI[i] = m, rR[r] -> c, 
   sSe[p, e] -> fe[t], iI[state] -> Int[fm[t], t], 
   cC[state] -> Int[v[t], t]}, \[Infinity]]
Scan[(eqn[#] = ToExpression@list[[#]]) &, Range@Length@list]

Comment: See above
It doesn't work but you should manage to understand my need
@march

Comment: `list` is still a `List` of `String`s. You can't use `Replace` on `String`s. Either use `StringReplace` on each element in `list` or do the replacement *after* you do the `Scan`. As it is, I think if you go through and understand what all the command in the answer are doing, you will be able to fix the problem on your own.

Comment: I hope I will enough clear on theses last comments. Don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: You right I should manage to modify the code now.Thank you. Otherwise, i don't understand this part of the code :  "\n\n" :> "\n". What \n means ? I ask Mathematica by pressing F1 but it didn't receive an answer. And why have you chosen a rule delayed ? Thank you in advance for your help. @march

Comment: `RuleDelayed` is just habit sometimes. It doesn't matter there. `"\n"` is the character that stands for "end-of-line". So any time a new line begins, MMA sees it as "\n". I'm just replacing two of them (there is an extra space between lines) with one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27427/discussion-between-bendesarts-and-march).

Comment: comm1 = StringReplace[commands, {"\n\n" :> "\n", "=" -> "=="}]
I try to adapt my code but it no longer works
comm2 = StringReplace[
  comm1, {"C_p_e " -> "fs[t]", "C_p_f " -> "v[t]", "R_p_e" -> "fd[t]",
    "I_p_e" -> "fm[t]", "C_c" = "1/k", "I_i" = "m", "R_r" -> "c", 
   "Se_p_e" -> "fe[t]", "I_state" -> "Int[fm[t],t]", 

   "C_state" -> "Int[v[t],t]"}]
Do you have an idea why the 2nd line doesn't work ? @march

Comment: I went to the chat and left some messages there that should help out. Otherwise, I have to move on to other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guarantee that the `Import` will work properly without having a sample ".m" file, but somewhere in my dim past, I've used MatLab, and I recall that ".m" files are simple text files. Therefore, we can do the following.

Suppose that the file in which you have stored

```
C_p_e = C_state/C_c;

C_p_f = I_state/I_i;

R_p_e = R_r*C_p_f;

I_p_e = (Se_p_e-R_p_e)-C_p_e;
```

is called `temp.m`. Then, we import the file as a `String` using

```
commands = Import["temp.m", "String"];
```

We then want to change the variable names that have underscores with the corresponding notation in MMA (which does not allow underscores in variable names).  Here's one possibility. We first replace all capital letters by lower-case ones so as not to conflict with built-in MMA commands (for instance, both `C` and `I` are built-in protected symbols in MMA). Since you are using lower-case and upper-case versions of the same letter, I will do, for instance, `cC` in place of `C`:

```
comm1 = StringReplace[commands, {"\n\n" :> "\n", a_?UpperCaseQ :> ToLowerCase[a] <> a}]
(* cC_p_e:=cC_state/cC_c;
   cC_p_f:=iI_state/iI_i;
   rR_p_e:=rR_r*cC_p_f;
   iI_p_e:=(sSe_p_e-rR_p_e)-cC_p_e; *)
```

(I have also gotten rid of the extra lines in between expressions for convenience.)

Next, we turn the underscores into brackets (in some sense):

```
comm2 = StringReplace[comm1
  , {"_" ~~ pat1 : LetterCharacter .. ~~ "_" ~~ pat2 : LetterCharacter .. :> "[" <> pat1 <> "," <> pat2 <> "]"
  , "_" ~~ pat : LetterCharacter .. :> "[" <> pat <> "]"}]
(* cC[p,e]=cC[state]/cC[c];
   cC[p,f]=iI[state]/iI[i];
   rR[p,e]=rR[r]*cC[p,f];
   iI[p,e]=(sSe[p,e]-rR[p,e])-cC[p,e]; *)
```

Finally, we evaluate this using

```
comm2 // ToExpression;
```

You will find, upon testing `?cC` that `cC[p,e]` has been set to `cC[state]/cC[c]` and `cC[p,f]` has been set to `iI[state]/iI[i]`.

---

Now, if you want to make MMA *equations*, modify the above with the following.

(1) Add `"=" -> "=="` to the first list of `StringReplace` replacements.

(2) After the rest has been executed, do

```
list = StringSplit[comm2, ";"];
Scan[(eqn[#] = ToExpression @ list[[#]]) &, Range@Length@list];
```

This will assign the equation `cC[p,f]==iI[state]/iI[i]` to `eqn[2]`, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
comm1 = StringReplace[commands, {"\n\n" :> "\n", "=" -> "=="}]

Comment: comm1 = StringReplace[commands, {"\n\n" :> "\n", "=" -> "=="}]
Can you explain me what the delayed rule "\n\n" :> "\n" is doing ?